# Unity Release build Error for Android 64bit

Tags: unity-game-engine, build

I use the Unity 2020.1.14. But Can't build android 64 bit APK build here. I have 3 error when build apk. [image]

As well as I configured unity build setting below. Please Request me What Should I do?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure `Api Compatibility Level` is set to `.net 4.x` like this :
[image]